# Is $f\left(t\right)=\frac{1}{t^2+1}$ of exponential order?

Tags: integration, laplace-transform

I'm learning Laplace Transforms and one of the questions I'm working on is the following:

$$\text{Is}\:\:f\left(t\right)=\frac{1}{t^2+1}\:\:\:\text{of exponential order?}$$

If so or if not, how do I show that? Obviously (or at least my guess) is that it would perhaps involve solving the Laplace Transform, resulting in

$$F\left(s\right)= \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\int_0^N \frac{e^{-st}}{t^2+1}\: dt=$$

but I don't know how to evaluate the integral...

Comment: Showing that a function is of exponential order does not require finding the Laplace transform. The reason for this being, in order for a Laplace Transform to exist in the first place, the function has to be of exponential order. You must thus first show that it is, in fact of exponential order (using the method I gave as an answer). :). I hope it helps and makes sense :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to show it, is using the following definition:

> A function $f(t)$ is of exponential order as $t \to \infty$ if:
>   $$\lim_{t \to \infty}\frac{|f(t)|}{e^{bt}}<\infty$$That is, if the limit exists and is finite.

Now, $f(t)=\frac{1}{t^2+1}$

Thus
\begin{align*}\lim_{t \to \infty}\frac{|\frac{1}{t^2+1}|}{e^{bt}} &= \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{\frac{1}{t^2+1}}{e^{bt}} =0\end{align*} 
(I will leave it to you to verify the above limit).

Hence, we know $f(t)=\frac{1}{t^2 +1}$ is of exponential order , as $t\to \infty$, provided that $b>0$.

---

**Note:**

This fits in with the "traditional" definition

> A function $f$ is said to be or exponential order as $t \to \infty$ if there are constants $M$, $b$ and $t_1$ existing such that $$|f(t)|<Me^{bt} \ \forall \ t \geq t_1$$

For example:

$$\text{If} \displaystyle \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{|f(t)|}{e^{bt}}=N, \text{then there exists a } t_1 \ \text{such that} \frac{|f(t)|}{e^{bt}}<N+1, \  \forall t > t_1, $$

that is $$f(t)< (N+1)e^{bt} = Me^{bt}, \ \forall t \geq t_1$$

---

Comment: I read the chapter in my book and it also spoke of the limit you've shown here. I think the wording threw me off -- they say "is _of_ exponential order", when it seems they might want to say "is _within_ exponential order." So it seems what they're playing with is the integrand of the Laplace transformation, ensuring that it is finite and the $f\left(t\right)$ is not out-growing the $e^{-st}$ in the "denominator".

Answer (score 2):

Usually the definition is that $f$ is of exponential order if there exist constants $C, a > 0$ such that

$$|f(t)| \leq Ce^{at} \ \ \ \ \hbox{ for all } \ t > 0$$

I suggest it's not hard to find such constants $C$ and $a$ here, as in fact $f$ is bounded: $$ \left|\frac{1}{t^2 +1}\right| \leq 1 \ \ \ \ \hbox{ for all } t$$